# Unable to use email as name of database in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

if I do mongoose.connect('whatever/email(as DB name)'), it throws errors. Is there any way to do it? I want to make a separate DB for each email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as below.

Have a users meta collection

```
{
  email:"a@action.com",
  uniqueId: 12
}
```

Use this `uniqueId` as collection name to store details.

But this would require two calls every time - one to find user collection and another one on querying the respective collection.

Comment: please upvote my question or i'll get banned from questions temporarily